# Install modules from minicpan with Carton

Tags: perl, cpanm, minicpan

I've had success getting cpanm to install from a minicpan mirror with `cpanm --mirror ~/.minicpan --mirror-only Module::Name`

But I can't figure out how to do the same with Carton.

I'd like to be able to just `carton install` when I'm offline / on a plane and tell it to use my minicpan mirror.

I've tried exporting like so `export PERL_CPANM_OPT="--mirror ~/.minicpan --mirror-only"` with no luck.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from miyagawa: `PERL_CARTON_MIRROR=/home/user/minicpan`